# Rails: Can't convert nil into string error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

**Before:** Using CarrierWave, I could update the image on a user profile with a new image without problem.

**Then:** I installed ImageMagick

**After:**  When I try to update the image on a User profile, I'm getting a "can't convert nil to string" error message.  However, if I don't select a new image and just press "update" it works fine (i.e. it shows the original image)

Can anyone see what the problem might be?

```
TypeError in UsersController#update

can't convert nil into String
Rails.root: /Users/mm/Sites/AT

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64:in `block in update'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:63:in `update'
```

Parameters

```
  {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"N1/rSIzBwYLFecQ59tCasRpt6Tst7GOSvdEob93ZrrA=",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"M",
 "email"=>"myemail@gmail.com",
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000102fef328 @original_filename="btc.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[image]\"; filename=\"btc.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/rc/rcFucU9oF5qT5vZE+tL1JE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20120226-20685-1x4k7ph>>},
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"2"}
```

UsersController

```
 def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Form

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :image %><br />

  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server since installing ImageMagick?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't start the server with the Amazon Key so the file wasn't getting uploaded, so it couldn't convert nil to a string when it tried to show the image.